# Match word only if not between double braces

Tags: regex, match

I'm trying to match all words that start with `$` and **are not between double braces** from a file as part of a validation of a json template file, where:

Should match: `"{$myWord.value}}"`

Should match: `"{{$otherWord.value}"`

Should match: `"{{$myWord.value"`

Should match: `"{    $somethingElse.value}}"`

Should match: `"$somethingElse.value"`

Should not match: `"{{$word.value}}"`

Should not match: `"{{word.value}}"`

**So far I've got the following regex
`/(?<=:.*)(?<!\{{2}(?:\s*))\$[a-z.1-9A-Z]+/gm`**

Where:

- `(?<=:.*)(?<!\{{2}(?:\s*))` checks that is the json value part of the file, doesn't contain the required double braces and might have empty spaces.
- `\$[a-z.1-9A-Z]+` checks if the following starts with the `$` symbol and contains any alphanumeric values.

But I still can't get the optional missing starting braces or the ending ones combination to work (the regex above only validates if the opening braces are missing).

This is an example of the json file I'm trying to validate:

```
{
    "groupId": "Test",
    "tokens": {
        "test1": {
            "$key": "$config.test",
            "$defaultValue": "{{$config.test}}"
        },
        "test2": {
            "$key": "show $config.test",
            "$defaultValue": "show {$config.test}}"
        },
        "test3": {
            "$key": "CodeExpression",
            "$defaultValue": "CodeExpression"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be deeply apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example check either `{{` to the left, or `}}` to the right as the character class does not match a curly:

```
(?<="[^{}]*)(?:{{\s*\$[a-z.1-9A-Z]+\s*}?|{?\s*\$[a-z.1-9A-Z]+\s*}})(?=")
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<="[^{}]*)` Positive lookbehind, assert `"` and optional repetitions other than `{` or `}` to the left
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `{{` Match literally
  - `\s*\$[a-z.1-9A-Z]+\s*` Match `$` and 1+ repetitions of the allowed characters in the character class between optional whitespace chars
  - `}?` Match an optional `}`
  - `|` Or
  - `{?\s*\$[a-z.1-9A-Z]+\s*}}` The other way around for the curly's
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?=")` Assert a `"` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y0Acqr/1)

Comment: Doesn't this fail the requirement: Should not match: `"{{word.value}}"`

Comment: @maksymiuk That would not match https://regex101.com/r/XhdNWt/1

Comment: I see a match on line 16, isn't that the same case?

Comment: {{$config.test}} should **not** match on the regex

Comment: @Wayrex I see, 1 moment, let me update it.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question a bit more. So the idea is to match any value that starts with `$` but is not encased between double braces to prompt the user that it is not correctly formatted (it SHOULD be between double braces) as `$` is a special character we're using as a reference to replace that value.

Comment: @Wayrex Perhaps like this `(?<="[^{}]*)(?:{{\s*\$[a-z.1-9A-Z]+\s*}?|{?\s*\$[a-z.1-9A-Z]+\s*}})(?=")` See  https://regex101.com/r/Y0Acqr/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird that's amazing, the only missing case would be of the value without any brace (just $config.test as it is also not correctly formatted).
Also, could the match return only $config.test, without the surrounding braces? (if not, it can always be cleaned up after the matchup)

Comment: @Wayrex Like this? `(?<="[^{"]*)(?:\$[a-z.1-9A-Z]+|{\s*\$[a-z.1-9A-Z]+\s*}}|{{\s*\$[a-z.1-9A-Z]+})(?=\s*",?$)` https://regex101.com/r/GXktMj/1 or like this https://regex101.com/r/xNOhqE/1

Comment: Seems like this approach is only working with unbalanced braces, so `{$config.test}` is not matching